# vue.js - вывод посчитанного значения

Tags: vue.js

Нужно чтобы в поле выводилась сумма -  текущего значения из цикла + значения из предыдущей итерации в цикле....

```
 <tr v-for="(bid, ind) in bids">
                        <th>{{bid.numberOfOrders}}</th>
                        <th>{{bids[ind].quantity + bids[ind-1].quantity}}</th>
                        <th>{{bid.quantity}}</th>
                        <th>{{bid.price}}</th>

                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте себе в methods  нужную функцию, в ко торую передайте ваш индекс и все будет хорошо.

Ну например

```js
methods: {
    computeMyBind: function (index) {
        let sum = this.bids[index].quantity;
        if (index > 0) {
            sum += this.bids[index-1].quantity;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Соответственно в нужной части шаблона пишете

```
<th>{{computeMyBind(ind)}}</th>
```

По идее это должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, а то я пробовал в Computed так сделать, оно не работает)

Comment: Computed чуть для другого, насколько я сам разобрался. Он считает нужные данные один раз при создании компонента и отслеживает в них изменения. Функции же в данном случае отрабатывают каждый раз  при об ращении к ним.

Comment: Тут я немного не верно изложил задачу, мне нужно чтобы каждое новое значение quantity прибавлялось к общей сумме quantity предыдущих и записывалось в поле

Comment: @AexFun ну можно попробовать в  ту же функцию передавать только индекс, формировать массив нужной  длины методом `slice` и дальше используем `array.reduce`

Но в JS я не особо силен.